# Intuitive reason why $ \frac1j > \int_{j}^{j+1} \frac1x dx $ for $j$ < $x$

Tags: calculus

In an Econometrics - Time Series textbook (Hamilton), I saw the claim, without proof:

Consider the sequence $ \psi_j $, then, for $ x > j $, $ \frac1j > \frac1x $, and therefore:

$$  \frac1j > \int_{j}^{j+1} \frac1x dx $$ for $x$ > $j$. When I plug in numbers for $j$, I see that this is indeed satisfied. But I'd like to know the intuition behind this or a proof.

Comment: What is meant by $x>j$? $x$ is an integration variable which varies from $j$ to $j+1$.

Comment: A plot might help. Recall that definite integrals are areas. https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+1%2Fx+and+1%2F5+from+x%3D5..6

Comment: @LightYagami - I've edited this to be more clear. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @CameronWilliams - The right side is an integral, while the left side is just a value. I can't grasp the intuition behind the reason why the whole area between $j$ and $j+1$ will be lesser than than just $\frac1j$.

Comment: @WorldGov I plotted the constant function 1/5 for a reason there.. What is the area under a rectangle with height 1/5 and base 1?

Comment: @CameronWilliams: .5. 
Are you trying to say that this value can simply be imagined as a rectangle of base 1? (and thus from $j$ to $j+1$?)

Comment: Yes that's exactly it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb R$ is decreasing (where $a<b$ are two real numbers), then for all $x\in(a,b]$, $f(x)<f(a)$, hence
$$
\int_a^bf(x)\,dx<\int_a^bf(a)\,dx=(b-a)f(a).
$$

Apply the latter with $a=j$, $b=j+1$ and $f:x\mapsto\frac1x$.

Comment: Both sides in your example is an integral; however, in the statement I gave, $\frac1j$ is a value, and not an integral, so why do we integrate both sides from $a$ to $b$ in your answer?

Comment: For the first inequality I used that if $f(x)<g(x)$ for all $x\in(a,b)$ then $\int_a^bf(x)\,dx<\int_a^bg(x)\,dx$. I applied this with $g(x)=f(a)$. Note that $f(a)$ is a constant, independent of $x$, hence its integral from $a$ to $b$ is equal to the length of the interval $[a,b]$ times $f(a)$, that is $(b-a)f(a)$. If you take $a=j$, $b=j+1$ and $f:x\mapsto\frac1x$ you have $(b-a)f(a)=(j+1-1)\frac1j=\frac1j$.

Answer (score 4):

On the interval $(j, j+1)$, $\dfrac1x < \dfrac1j$. Hence $\displaystyle\int_j^{j+1}\frac1x dx < \frac1j \cdot (j+1-j) = \frac1j$.